# Http Post parameters to url don't send special characters "+" in objectC Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I have create an application that send two POST parameters to aspx server and it's save data in database.
It's an Iphone Application.

Here's the code:

```
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&number=%@", 
        name,number];
        NSString *capturedpost = [post 
        stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData *postData = [capturedpost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData 
        length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/www.myurl.aspx"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        //[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        //[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
        NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
     returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler 
    bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
    returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

But on server, the string "number" that contain the telephone number like "+393333..." save in db the number without the "+".
How can I do?
The server side works fine, because the same App on Android that do same request work perfect!

Comment: You normally put the parameters to POST requests within the body of the request, not on the URL, like a PUT request.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for here. what is your problem? do you want to save the number _without_ `+`? then remove it before you post... do you want to save it _with_ `+`, you need to encode the URL properly before posting a `+` as `%2B`.

Comment: I want to save it with "+". How I can encode it as %2B?

Answer (score 3):

OK, thanks to "holex" I successfully encode the URL in this way:

```
 NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                                       NULL,
                                                                                       (CFStringRef)post,
                                                                                       NULL,
                                                                                       (CFStringRef)@"+",
                                                                                       kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));
```

And the "+" saved correctly in db!